# How to highlight the multiple dates in a calendar for different months using Javavscript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a calendar using HTML and Javascript in my calendar I have highlighted some dates in a particular month using Jquery but I want to highlight the multiple dates in all the months. In my calendar months and years are displayed using dropdown list and the dates are displayed using HTML table please give the solution

This is my code

HTML Code

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="calendar1">
            <h3 class="card-header" id="monthAndYear"></h3>
            </div>
            <head>
            <div class="cal">
            <form class="form-inline">

            <label class="jumpto col-md-4" for="month">Jump To: </label>
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="month" id="month" onchange="jump()">

                <option value=0>Jan</option>
                <option value=1>Feb</option>
                <option value=2>Mar</option>
                <option value=3>Apr</option>
                <option value=4>May</option>
                <option value=5>Jun</option>
                <option value=6>Jul</option>
                <option value=7>Aug</option>
                <option value=8>Sep</option>
                <option value=9>Oct</option>
                <option value=10>Nov</option>
                <option value=11>Dec</option>
            </select>
             <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <label for="year"></label><select class="form-control col-md-6" name="year" id="year" onchange="jump()">
            <option value=2018>2018</option>
            <option value=2019>2019</option>
            <option value=2020>2020</option>
            <option value=2021>2021</option>
        </select></form>
        <div id="calendar" >
            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md" cellpadding="20"  >

            <tr bgcolor="white">
                <th>Sun</th>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <th>Tue</th>
                <th>Wed</th>
                <th>Thu</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <th>Sat</th>
            </tr>

            <tbody id="calendar-body" style="color:black;" bgcolor="white">

            </tbody >
        </table>
</div>
        <div class="form-inline">

            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-md-5" id="previous" onclick="previous()">Previous</button>
             <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-md-5" id="next" onclick="next()">Next</button>
        </div>
        <br/>
        </head>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code

```
<script>
    let today = new Date();
let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
let selectYear = document.getElementById("year");
let selectMonth = document.getElementById("month");

let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

let monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);


function next() {
    currentYear = (currentMonth === 11) ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear;
    currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}

function previous() {
    currentYear = (currentMonth === 0) ? currentYear - 1 : currentYear;
    currentMonth = (currentMonth === 0) ? 11 : currentMonth - 1;
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}

function jump() {
    currentYear = parseInt(selectYear.value);
    currentMonth = parseInt(selectMonth.value);
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}

function showCalendar(month, year) {

    let firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
    let daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();

    let tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body"); // body of the calendar

    // clearing all previous cells
    tbl.innerHTML = "";

    // filing data about month and in the page via DOM.
    monthAndYear.innerHTML = months[month] + " " + year;
    selectYear.value = year;
    selectMonth.value = month;

    // creating all cells
    let date = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        // creates a table row
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        //creating individual cells, filing them up with data.
        for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode("");
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

            }
            else if (date > daysInMonth) {
                break;
            }

            else {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
                if (date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()) {
                    cell.classList.add("bg-info");
                } // color today's date
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
                date++;

            }


        }

        tbl.appendChild(row); // appending each row into calendar body.


            //debugger;

    var mnth=[<?php echo $month2; ?>];
    //alert(mnth);
    mnth=mnth.toString();
     mn=mnth.split(',');
             mlength=mn.length;
             //  alert(mlength);
                 for( var j=1;j< mlength;j++){
                     var newmn=mn[j];
                    // alert(newmn);
$('select#month').find('option').each(function() {
    var data1=$(this).val();
    //alert(data1);
    if (data1==newmn){
        //alert(data1);

    var ary=[<?php echo $value; ?>];
         //alert(ary);
     ldate=ary.toString();
     ldate=ldate.split(',');
    //   alert(ldate);
         llength=ldate.length;
    //   alert(llength);

       for ( var i = 0; i <llength; i++) {
        var newdate= ldate[i];

          $('#calendar > table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    $(this).children('td').each(function(){
   var data = $(this).html();

    if (data==newdate)      
    {
     $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    }


                                       })



                                   });

                                       }
         }              
});
}
 }
    }                
  </script>
```

var dates =[2019-12-21,2019-12-22,2019-12-23,2019-12-25,2019-12-26,2019-12-31,2020-01-01,2020-01-02,2019-12-28];

Comment: _"please give the solution"_ That's not how this site works. We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please provide  your code and your calendar library, so that developers can help you to sort out the issuse

Comment: keep all the dates that you need to highlight in an arrary and loop through all the dates in the calendar and add the css to highlight it.

Answer (score 1):

Provide your code and calendar library to giving a better solution for you. Suggest answer for you can start developing...

```js
var dates = ['01/10/2020', '01/20/2020', '01/30/2020'];

$('#date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays
});

function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
```

```css
td.highlight > a {
 background: #F0DC23!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="date"></div>
```